# Force R&OS dynamic pdf to download php

Tags: php, pdf, dynamic, force-download

I made a dynamic pdf file using R&OS pdf class for php and everything works fine, you open the php an the browser displays the pdf file.
But my client just told me they need to display it inside a small iframe, so they asked me to force it to download so the user doesnt end up with this letter size pdf file shrinked down to 500px.
I'm not that familiar with the R&OS pdf class but I couldn't find a way to do this, not eve with this code

```
`<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=huge_document.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile('huge_document.pdf');
?>`
```

maybe i just didn't know where to place the code properly, Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Not sure whether this can help you, but you can try to add the following PHP commands before the readfile: `header('Content-Encoding: gzip'); while (@ob_end_clean()); ob_start('ob_gzhandler'); readfile('huge_document.pdf');` (sometimes it can help)

Comment: what i mean is that it doesn't download the file, it continues to display it in the browser.
I tried what you suggested after my code:

    `if (isset($_GET['d']) && $_GET['d']){
    $pdfcode = $pdf->ezOutput(1);
    $pdfcode = str_replace("\n","\n<br>",htmlspecialchars($pdfcode));
    echo '<html><body>';
    echo trim($pdfcode);
    echo '</body></html>';}
    else {
    $pdf->ezStream(array('compress'=>0));}
    header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
    while (@ob_end_clean());
    ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
    readfile($pdf);`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this Sussie:

example.php

```html
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
 $text = 'Example text';
 include './src/Cezpdf.php'; // http://pdf-php.sourceforge.net/
 $pdf = new Cezpdf();
 $pdf->ezText($text,50);
 $pdfcode = $pdf->ezOutput(1);
 file_put_contents('huge_document.pdf', $pdfcode);

 if (isset($_GET['d']) && $_GET['d']){
   header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="huge_document.pdf"');
   header('Content-type: application/pdf'); // or 'application/octet-stream'
   header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
   while (@ob_end_clean());
   ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
   readfile('huge_document.pdf');
   exit;
 }
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head> 
 <body>
 <p><a href="?d=download">Download</a></p>
 <iframe src="file.pdf" width="500" height="700"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```